# How to convert each value of a dataframe column by an identifying integer

Tags: python, pandas, converters

I have the following dataframe :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(NoMatter=list(range(6)), Value=['a','b',7,7,'b','b']))
print(df)
   NoMatter Value
0         0     a
1         1     b
2         2     7
3         3     7
4         4     b
5         5     b
```

I would like to modify the Value column such as it contains a different integer by old values. Here, I would like therefore 1 instead of each a, 2 instead of each b and 3 instead of each 7.

Expected result :

```
   NoMatter  Value
0         0      1
1         1      2
2         2      3
3         3      3
4         4      2
5         5      2
```

How please could I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df['Value'] = pd.factorize(df['Value'])[0] + 1
print (df)
   NoMatter  Value
0         0      1
1         1      2
2         2      3
3         3      3
4         4      2
5         5      2
```